# Tkinter: drag select area, get image from selected area

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

I´m using a tkinter gui that I want to expand. The goal is that

- you can draw a rectangle by dragging over the canvas
- then the selected area can be accessed as an image

How to achieve this in tkinter?

Comment: Relevant [creating-object-on-canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827578) and [canvas-creating-rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039564)

Comment: Drawing the rectangle is easy, but there is no way to get the area inside the rectangle as an image. At least, not with `Tkinter`.

Comment: ***"but there is no way"***: There is no `tkinter` method to do this, but could simple be done by replacing the `rectangle` with a image sizede/placed according the `rectangle.coords`.